# Grunt Watch LESS files in folder and create css when less file is changed

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I am looking for GRUNT automation task which watches the less files in the root directory and gives us the css files of the same name as the less files in the same directory like

```
Root Folder

    package.json
    Gruntfile.js
    Folder1
        file1.less
        file2.less
    Folder2
        file3.less
        file4.less
```

My Gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({
        //our LESS options
        less: {
          development: {
            files: {
              "": "" //not able to write this line, how can i mention which file to compile as i am watching the entire folder
            }
          }

        },

      watch: {
          css: {
            files: '**/*.less',
            tasks: ['less']

          }
      }


    });

    //load our tasks
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

    //default tasks to run
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['less']);



}
```

Not able to mention the source less file name and result css file name in less task config, as i am watching the entire folder, i want to create the css file for the corresponding less file in the same path as less, whenever particular css is changed. Want to compile the less file which is changed , not all the less files to be compiled, if one less is changed.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Can you write the folder structure to be sure to understand what is expected?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [grunt-newer](https://github.com/tschaub/grunt-newer) to configure you less task to run with newer files only.

- `npm install grunt-newer --save-dev`

once the plugin is installed, add

- `grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-newer');`

edit the watch task:

```
watch: {
    css: {
      files: '**/*.less',
      tasks: ['newer:less']
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [grunt.js docu](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically) and see how to build files object dynamically.